# Accessing input type file at server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload

I am using the `<input type="file" />` tag to upload a file to the server. How do I access the file at the server side and store it at the server? (The file is an image file)

The client side code is :

```
<form id="form1" action="PhotoStore.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="preview(this)" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Photostore.aspx.cs has

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 1;
            foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in Request.Files)
            {
                int contentLength = postedFile.ContentLength;
                string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
                string fileName = postedFile.FileName;

                postedFile.SaveAs(@"c:\test\file" + index + ".tmp");

                index++;
            } 

        }
```

I tried uploading a jpg file. Not able to see a saved file. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to add `id` and `runat="server"` attributes like this:

```
<input type="file" id="MyFileUpload" runat="server" />
```

Then, on the server-side you'll have access to the control's [`PostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputfile.postedfile.aspx) property, which will give you [`ContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contentlength.aspx), [`ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contenttype.aspx), [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename.aspx), [`InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx) properties and a [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx) method etc:

```
int contentLength = MyFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
string contentType = MyFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
string fileName = MyFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;

MyFileUpload.PostedFile.Save(@"c:\test.tmp");
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Request.Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) which gives you a collection of all uploaded files:

```
int index = 1;
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in Request.Files)
{
    int contentLength = postedFile.ContentLength;
    string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
    string fileName = postedFile.FileName;

    postedFile.Save(@"c:\test" + index + ".tmp");

    index++;
}
```

Comment: why runat ="server" ? I donot want a server control. Will this work without a server control?

Comment: If you don't want to use a server control then you can use `Request.Files`, which will give you a collection containing a `HttpPostedFile` object for each uploaded file.

Comment: Thank you so much @LukeH...You got me out of trouble...:)

Comment: what if my method is static, i m unable to use that than.?

Answer (score 2):

I think the name tag is required on the file input:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Without this, I don’t get anything back.

---

Further problems that I had which might be specific to my machine:

I get a

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'.
```

error at the line

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in Request.Files)
```

so my final code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    var postedFile = Request.Files[i]; 

    // do something with file here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the asp:FileUpload control provided by ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the FileUpload control in the toolbox, Give your input an ID then use form[id] to access the input field and cast it to HtmlInputFile.

example here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileupload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you give the input-tag an id and add the runat="server" attribute then you can access it easily.
First change your input tag: `<input type="file" id="FileUpload" runat="server" />`
Then add the following to your Page_Load method:

```
if (FileUpload.PostedFile != null) 
{
  FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"some path here");
}
```

This will write your file to a folder of your choice. You can access the PostedFile object if you need to determine the file type or original file name.