# FileUpload.HasFile always shows false

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Iam loading three fileupload controls dynamically thru the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
       Table tblDocuments = new Table();
        tblDocuments.CellPadding=8;
        tblDocuments.CellSpacing=8;

        TableRow tr7 = new TableRow();

        TableCell tc13 = new TableCell();
        Label lblSRV=new Label();
        lblSRV.Text="SRV:";
        tc13.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4FB0B0");
        lblSRV.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        lblSRV.Font.Bold=true;
        tc13.Controls.Add(lblSRV);
        tr7.Cells.Add(tc13);

        TableCell tc14 = new TableCell();
        fuUploadSRV.ID = "SRV";
        tc14.Controls.Add(fuUploadSRV);
        tc14.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        tc14.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;

        tr7.Cells.Add(tc14);
        tblDocuments.Rows.Add(tr7);

        TableRow tr8 = new TableRow();

        TableCell tc15 = new TableCell();           
        Label lblMAtrialCertificate = new Label();
        lblMAtrialCertificate.Text = "Material/Product Certificate:";
        lblMAtrialCertificate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        lblMAtrialCertificate.Font.Bold = true;
        tc15.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4FB0B0");
        tc15.Controls.Add(lblMAtrialCertificate);
        tr8.Cells.Add(tc15);

        TableCell tc16 = new TableCell();
        fuUploadMaterialCertificate.ID = "MaterialCertificate";
        tc16.Controls.Add(fuUploadMaterialCertificate);
        tc16.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        tc16.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;

        tr8.Cells.Add(tc16);
        tblDocuments.Rows.Add(tr8);


        TableRow tr9 = new TableRow();

        TableCell tc17 = new TableCell();
        Label lblPurchaseOrder = new Label();
        lblPurchaseOrder.Text = "Purchase Order:";
        lblPurchaseOrder.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        lblPurchaseOrder.Font.Bold = true;
        tc17.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4FB0B0");
        tc17.Controls.Add(lblPurchaseOrder);
        tr9.Cells.Add(tc17);

        TableCell tc18 = new TableCell();
        fuUploadPurchaseOrder.ID="Purchase";
        tc18.Controls.Add(fuUploadPurchaseOrder);
        tc18.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        tc18.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;

        tr9.Cells.Add(tc18);
        tblDocuments.Rows.Add(tr9);

        placeSubmit.Controls.Add(tblDocuments);
```

}

Iam processing the file in the button click event

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (fuUploadSRV.HasFile)
        {
            string srvFilename = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadSRV.PostedFile.FileName);
            Stream fs = fuUploadSRV.PostedFile.InputStream;
            int filesize = fuUploadSRV.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] content = br.ReadBytes(filesize);
            Objects.UpdateSRVFileDetails(srvFilename, content,txtSRV.Text.ToString().Trim());

        }

        if (fuUploadMaterialCertificate.HasFile)
        {
            string materialFilename = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadMaterialCertificate.PostedFile.FileName);
            Stream fs = fuUploadMaterialCertificate.PostedFile.InputStream;
            int filesize = fuUploadMaterialCertificate.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] content = br.ReadBytes(filesize);
            Objects.UpdateMaterialCertificateFileDetails(materialFilename, content, txtSRV.Text.ToString().Trim());
        }

        if (fuUploadPurchaseOrder.HasFile)
        {
            string poFilename = Path.GetFileName(fuUploadPurchaseOrder.PostedFile.FileName);
            Stream fs = fuUploadPurchaseOrder.PostedFile.InputStream;
            int filesize = fuUploadPurchaseOrder.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] content = br.ReadBytes(filesize);
            Objects.UpdatePurchaseOrderFileDetails(poFilename, content, txtPurchaseOrderNo.Text.ToString().Trim());
        }
```

}

Now while debugging, though I am choosing a file, the fuUploadSRV.HasFile,fuUploadMaterialCertificate.HasFile,fuUploadPurchaseOrder.HasFile is always returning false.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you instantiated your new fileUpload control? As I have seen in your code, you only stated its id via `fuUploadPurchaseOrder.ID="Purchase";`, but no instantiation.

Comment: Thank you ..I instantiate all the file upload controls

Comment: I instantiated all the controls outside Page_load...

Comment: Did you try adding the controls in Page_Init?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try updating your `<form runat="server"` to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Weird things may happen without it!

Comment: Ya...I did it but what is happening is when I click the submit button, the page is getting post back and the control is being created again. In this process, the choosen file is lost. The page load event is happening first and then the click event..I donno how to catch the file .

Comment: I'd guess that your issue is related to not fully recreating your control state with every postback. When you create a page dynamically with .NET controls, you have to ensure that the control state is full re-created with each postback. There are a lot of resources on the internet that cover this, including this SO post for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3945390/442472. MSDN covers this as well.

Comment: If you don't want to recreate the control state, you can probably also check Request.Form[] variables. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431407/get-file-upload-data-from-post-data-in-asp-net or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998452/accessing-input-type-file-at-server-side-in-asp-net for a discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

The file upload control is in update panel. When I removed the update panel, the control worked as predicted. But I dint understand how update panel played a role, but removing this has solved my problem.

Comment: I've seen strange behavior with update panels and posted files. I try to avoid mixing the two if I can.