# Code behind image input in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my code :

```
<label for="image" >Image input</label>    
<input id="image" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

i don’t know the code behind to get value from the inserted image and save it in my project folder. please help me. thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing input type file at server side in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998452/accessing-input-type-file-at-server-side-in-asp-net)

Comment: hey @artm thankyou for the answer but i dont know why still error
on my aspx :
<label for="image" >Image input</label>    
<input  id="image" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" runat="server">

on my aspx.cs :
int contentLength = image.PostedFile.ContentLength;
string contentType = image.PostedFile.ContentType;
string fileName = image.PostedFile.FileName;
image.PostedFile.Save(@"c:\test.tmp");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access what is put into the files collection using jScript:

```
function SaveImage()
{
    var uploadFileElement = document.getElementById("image");
    var theFile = uploadFileElement.files[0];

    // Use AJAX or call a PageMethod to initiate Server Side Processing
    // to Save the file
}
```

Just add a standard html button on your form that calls this function to initiate the saving of your file.

If you want to use standard Server Side (ASP.NET Controls), I would suggest using the FileUpload control.

Put this in your aspx page:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_UploadFile" runat="server"  />
<asp:Button ID="Button_UploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload File" onclick="Button_UploadFile_Click" />
```

Put this in your code behind (.cs):

```
private void Button_UploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload_UploadFile.HasFile)
    {
        // IMPLEMENT YOUR CODE FOR SAVING THE FILE
    }
}
```

Comment: i still new in this webprog and C# , I 've never touch jScript and AJAX before